# VBA Error 1004 - ChangeFileAccess Method Failed - File on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm fixing some code written by a colleague and I've come across this hurdle where an Excel document is opened from a Sharepoint and the ChangeFileAccess method is run to change it to Read/Write. The method fails with error code 1004. The file opens so everything up to that point is working. 
I can't see why it won't work, I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable than I can!
I've removed the file path and document name for the sake of anonymity.
I'm using Office 365, code in question below:

```
Dim ObjFileA, ObjfileB As File
FilePathA = "filepath" & fileName
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set ObjFileA = FSO.GetFile(FilePathA)
Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(ObjFileA, False, False)

wbA.Activate
wbA.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadWrite)
Set wbA = Workbooks(fileName)
```

Comment: Looks to me like `wbA = Nothing` at the time you're trying to `ChangeFileAccess` because the `Set wbA = Workbooks(filename)` line is _after_ the `ChangeFileAccess` line.

Comment: My understanding is that the line Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(ObjFileA, False, False) sets the wbA object equal to the workbook in question. I have tried adding Set wbA = Workbooks(fileName) before the ChangeFilesAccess line too though and it still produced the same error.

Comment: Yup, missed seeing the `Set wbA = Workbooks.Open()` line. Is `ObjFileA` set to a valid path\filename and the workbook is successfully being opened?

Comment: Yeah the file path is good and the file opens properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your file *already* being opened as Read-Write?

I just encountered a similar problem to what you describe (Err 1004 when changing the access method, though in my case I was attempting to change the access to Read-Only on a file that was already Read-Only.)

After some testing, I get the error every time if I try to invoke wkbk.ChangeFileAccess to "change" the access type to be the same as the current access type.

If you find that the workbook might already be Read-Write, then I suggest a change to :

```
If wbA.ReadOnly then wbA.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadWrite)
```

Comment: Yes, you are spot on. I realised this as well after forgetting about this post. Although the file does have the "Edit Workbook" at the top, I could still change it through VBA.